# vinyl-ftp does no upload

Tags: ftp, npm, gulp

I am trying to upload a folder via ftp using gulp and vinyl-ftp (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-ftp).
However, using the example configuration the task runs through but it does nothing.

There seems to be a log function, but i couldn't figure out if i get any logs. I only get the standart output from gulp:

```
[08:54:22] Using gulpfile gulpfile.js
[08:54:22] Starting 'deploy'...
[08:54:22] Finished 'deploy' after 13 ms
```

I just slightly modified the example configuration to fit my needs:

```
var gulp = require( 'gulp' );
var gutil = require( 'gulp-util' );
var ftp = require( 'vinyl-ftp' );

gulp.task( 'deploy', function() {

var conn = ftp.create( {
    host:     'mywebsite.tld',
    user:     'me',
    password: 'mypass',
    parallel: 10,
    log: gutil.log
} );

var globs = [
    'src/**',
    'css/**',
    'js/**',
    'fonts/**',
    'index.html'
];


return gulp.src( globs, { base: 'path_to_my_folder', buffer: false } )
    .pipe( conn.newer( '/path_to_remote_folder' ) ) 
    .pipe( conn.dest( '/path_to_remote_folder' ) );

} );
```

May i miss any dependency? I am running Yosemite.

Comment: When vinyl-ftp runs on Node 8 it stops calculating the server time offset property and needs a manual timeOffset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick shot: I think the `base` attribute is misused here. `base` takes some part in your glob and ignores that for further file names. What you need is `cwd`:

```
return gulp.src( globs, { cwd: 'path_to_my_folder', buffer: false } )
    .pipe( conn.newer( '/path_to_remote_folder' ) ) 
    .pipe( conn.dest( '/path_to_remote_folder' ) );
});
```

Comment: how to empty the remote folder before uploading new files?